# PHP validation using PDO not working

Tags: php, validation, pdo

I am new to PDO. I have included validation in the following code but it doesnt seem to work and no message appears if users enter the wrong username/password. Please show me where I am going wrong. I have numerous times to get this working but no luck. Thanks

```
<?php 
require("config.php"); 
$submitted_username = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $login_ok = false; 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        } 
        if($check_password === $row['password']){
            $login_ok = true;
        } 
    } 

    if($login_ok){ 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;  
        header("Location: secret.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to: secret.php"); 
    } 
    else{ 
        print("Login Failed."); 
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
  } 
?>
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php 

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = "xxxx"; 
$password = "xxxx"; 
$host = "xxxxxxx"; 
$dbname = "xxxxxx"; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
} 
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
} 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
session_start(); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you `echo $stmt->errorCode();`? It should show a string of `00000` if nothing is wrong with the query itself.

Comment: Did you try print_r($row) to see what it contains?

Comment: In your `config.php` or elsewhere have you actually configured PDO to throw exceptions via `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`? If not, that `try/catch` won't be of much help.

Comment: Not sure if it is for debugging, but you'll want to replace `die('Redirecting to...')` with a bare `exit()` call, to avoid `headers already sent` warnings.

Comment: when I tried print_r($row). It returned - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$submitted_username' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\index.php on line 48

Comment: Try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';` and don't forget the semi-colon =)

Comment: Where do I place that code @user2191572

Comment: Which code, the `print_r()`?  Place it right inside `if ($row)`. If you mean the `setAttribute()`, that should be called as `$db->setAttribute(...)` just after connecting to the DB and before anything else.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: i have it in config file. I will edit my question to include my config.php

Comment: @codingman after `$row = $stmt->fetch();`